# React axios not working it's says failed to compile

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new in React . I am trying to get my api data with axios . But getting error . My code are :

```
  import React from 'react';
  import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
  import axios from 'axios';

  class App extends React.Component{
      axios.get('http://example.com')
        .then(function (response) {
          // handle success
          console.log(response);
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
          // handle error
          console.log(error);
        })
        .then(function () {
          // always executed
        });

      render() {
          return(
              <div className="container">
                  <p>Lorem Ipsum Dolor</p>
              </div>
          );
      }
  }

  ReactDOM.render(<App />,document.getElementById('root'));
```

Getting the errors Lists of :

> Failed to compile
>
> ./src/index.js
>   Syntax error: Unexpected token (7:7)
>
> 6 | class App extends React.Component{
>
> 7 |  axios.get('http://example.com')
>
> 8 |    .then(function (response) {
>
> 9 |      // handle success
>
> 10 |      console.log(response);
>
> This error occurred during the build time and cannot be dismissed.

Comment: Don't you need to import React?

Comment: You have a method call just hanging out in the body of the class, when did you expect it to get called?

Comment: You could read about correct class body definition here [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put call function inside constructor or componentDidMount function like

```
 class App extends React.Component{
    constructor(props) {
     super(props);
     axios.get('http://example.com') //...
    }

    componentDidMount(){
      //or here or to other lifecycle function based on needs
    }


    render() {
        return(
            <div className="container">
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this to the top of the document

```
import React from 'react';
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, add `import React from 'react';` to the beggining of your file.

Second of all, when you want to make an AJAX call when a component is rendered to the DOM, you should put the call inside `componentDidMount()`.

In your situation the code should be something like this:

```
  import React from 'react';
  import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
  import axios from 'axios';

  class App extends React.Component {
    componentDidMount() {
      axios.get('http://example.com')
        .then(function (response) {
          // handle success
          console.log(response);
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
          // handle error
          console.log(error);
        })
        .then(function () {
          // always executed
        });

      render() {
          return(
              <div className="container">
                  <p>Lorem Ipsum Dolor</p>
              </div>
          );
      }
    }   
  }
  ReactDOM.render(<App />,document.getElementById('root'));
```

You can read more about component lifecycle methods [here](https://engineering.musefind.com/react-lifecycle-methods-how-and-when-to-use-them-2111a1b692b1).

Comment: Should i use the render() inside the component didmount?

Comment: No, render is a function that the component uses to render HTML onto the screen. You use lifecycle methods in order to make AJAX calls, add & remove events listeners, or check if the component should render.

Answer (score 0):

You should pass axios method in componentDidMount like this:

```
componentDidMount() {
      axios.get('http://example.com/api/api/topCardNews')
        .then(function (response) {
          // handle success
          console.log(response);
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
          // handle error
          console.log(error);
        })
        .then(function () {
          // always executed
        });
    }
```

also you should import react

```
import { React, ReactDOM } from 'react-dom';
```

You can read react axios tutorial here: https://alligator.io/react/axios-react/